# Can a Floated Element Affect "Cousin" Elements?

Tags: html, css

**In what all cases does a floated element push other elements and/or text out of the way?**

For example, can floats ever push a "cousin" element around (or any other text/element that requires traversing *up* the DOM)?

My understanding is that floated elements will overlap only adjacent elements (and their contents) but will then push text and inline/inline-block elements out of the way so no overlap occurs. I've had a few times where float behavior has surprised me in the past so I'd like to verify what I thought I knew.

Comment: What exactly is unclear in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)?

Comment: @Oka It says "text and inline elements will wrap around it" but doesn't specify where in the DOM tree those text and inline elements need to be (relative to the floated element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

> Block formatting contexts are important for the positioning (see [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)) and clearing (see [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)) of floats. The rules for positioning and clearing of floats apply only to things within the same block formatting context. Floats do not affect the layout of things in other block formatting contexts, and clear only clears past floats in the same block formatting context.

- [Block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)